# Monotouch: Library with a Foundation.Register class

Tags: attributes, xamarin.ios

I have an additional Libary project which has a custom button classs:

> [MonoTouch.Foundation.Register("ItunesIphoneOpen")]
>     public class ItunesIphoneOpen: UIButton

When I set the class of a button in UIBuilder to ItunesIphoneOpen the partial code that is generated does not know about this class as it is in another namespace (and project)

Howe can I get the generated code to include a namespace reference to the namespace of ItunesIphoneOpen?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to go into the *.designer.cs file and specify the namespace yourself.  The standard MonoTouch.UIKit classes get handled automatically but I don't think the tool that generates the designer file will generate the namespace for custom UI classes.